# amCharts: Filter JSON

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I'm using amCharts to show quarterly sales-figures from a Company since the year 2000.

All the data in the quarterly graphs is coming from one Array like this very simplified one:

```
var myNumbers = [{
  "quarter":"2000 Q1",
  "CountX":2407,
  "CountY":8788,
  "CountZ":3421
},{
  …
},{
  "quarter":"2016 Q3",
  "CountX":4252,
  "CountY":12387,
  "CountZ":43446
},{
  "quarter":"2016 Q4",
  "CountX":4886,
  "CountY":16879,
  "CountZ":43446
}]
```

What I can accomplish with amCharts very easily with this VAR is to show a large Graph with alle the quarters present … Q1 2000, Q2 2000, Q3 2000, Q4 2000, Q1 2001, Q2 2001 and so on till Q4 2016.

But now I would like to add a Graph, that lets the users choose to **only display all the Q1** or *all the Q3 **from all years***, so they can compare all the Q1-Quarters from 2000 thru 2017 WITHOUT all the Q2, Q3 and Q4 … or all the Q2 from 2000 to 2017 WITHOUT the Q1, Q3 and Q4 and so forth.

How is that possible, without me having to add another JS-Variable with the data only from the Q1s of every year, and one more with only from the Q2 of every year, etc.p.p.? It would be great, if I could use the same one big var for all graphs, since the data is (in my perception ;-) ) *really heavy*. So cutting that data array would probably be best.

The best solution, of course, would be, if I could add a (second) interactive Legend to the graphs, where the user can choose to only display «Q1» or «Q2» — or something like that.

It appears that in the Knowledgebase to amCharts, there already is something similar https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-changing-data-granularity-serial-chart/ … but how can I adapt this solution, that it works with 4 links («Q1», «Q2», «Q3», «Q4») instead of a select-dropdown and shows me all the Q1s, Q2s etc. of all years if I click them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to filter your chart like how you're describing. You'll need to use custom HTML and JS to update the chart.

To build upon the knowledge base example, you can create external links/buttons in HTML and attach listeners to them that filters your data, updates the chart's dataProvider and calls `validateData`. Since your data isn't using a date-based category axis, you don't need to worry about `minPeriod` or any other date-based properties mentioned in the knowledge base.

Here's one approach:

```js
var chartData = [{
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 16,
  "CountZ": 63,
  "quarter": "2001 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 35,
  "CountX": 19,
  "CountZ": 53,
  "quarter": "2001 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 46,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2001 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 16,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2001 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 21,
  "CountZ": 63,
  "quarter": "2002 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 41,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2002 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 67,
  "quarter": "2002 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 54,
  "quarter": "2002 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 47,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 70,
  "quarter": "2003 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 48,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2003 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 40,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 51,
  "quarter": "2003 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2003 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 49,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 64,
  "quarter": "2004 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2004 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 27,
  "CountZ": 57,
  "quarter": "2004 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2004 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 41,
  "CountX": 30,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2005 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 40,
  "CountX": 27,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2005 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 17,
  "CountZ": 56,
  "quarter": "2005 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 41,
  "CountX": 26,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2005 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 49,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 59,
  "quarter": "2006 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 17,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2006 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2006 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 40,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2006 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 57,
  "quarter": "2007 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2007 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 21,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2007 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 70,
  "quarter": "2007 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2008 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 30,
  "CountZ": 69,
  "quarter": "2008 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 26,
  "CountZ": 53,
  "quarter": "2008 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 30,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2008 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 70,
  "quarter": "2009 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2009 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2009 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 27,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2009 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 42,
  "CountX": 28,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2010 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2010 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2010 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 45,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2010 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2011 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2011 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 21,
  "CountZ": 64,
  "quarter": "2011 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 48,
  "CountX": 23,
  "CountZ": 69,
  "quarter": "2011 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 49,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 56,
  "quarter": "2012 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 19,
  "CountZ": 51,
  "quarter": "2012 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2012 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 42,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2012 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 46,
  "CountX": 18,
  "CountZ": 59,
  "quarter": "2013 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 51,
  "quarter": "2013 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2013 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 35,
  "CountX": 28,
  "CountZ": 61,
  "quarter": "2013 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 19,
  "CountZ": 63,
  "quarter": "2014 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 16,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2014 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 57,
  "quarter": "2014 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 44,
  "CountX": 26,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2014 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 23,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2015 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 46,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2015 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 48,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 61,
  "quarter": "2015 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 50,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2015 Q4"
}];

function filterByQuarter(quarter) {
  return function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.quarter.indexOf(quarter) !== -1;
  }
}

function filterData(quarter) {
  chart.dataProvider = chartData.filter(filterByQuarter(quarter));
  chart.validateData();
}

function resetChart() {
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.validateData();
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.filterButton'),
  function(button) {
    if (button.dataset.quarter === "reset") {
      button.addEventListener('click', resetChart);
    } else {
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        filterData(button.dataset.quarter);
      });
    }
  }
);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "categoryField": "quarter",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountX"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountY"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountZ"
  }]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q1">Q1</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q2">Q2</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q3">Q3</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q4">Q4</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**Edit**

For multiple charts, you can modify the above code to take chart instances as parameters and then modify the listener methods to pass the chart object in as one of the parameters. This is made easier if you attach the chart ids to the buttons' data attribute to tie them together easier.

```js
var charts = {};
var chartData = [{
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 16,
  "CountZ": 63,
  "quarter": "2001 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 35,
  "CountX": 19,
  "CountZ": 53,
  "quarter": "2001 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 46,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2001 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 16,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2001 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 21,
  "CountZ": 63,
  "quarter": "2002 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 41,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2002 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 67,
  "quarter": "2002 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 54,
  "quarter": "2002 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 47,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 70,
  "quarter": "2003 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 48,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2003 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 40,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 51,
  "quarter": "2003 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2003 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 49,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 64,
  "quarter": "2004 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2004 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 27,
  "CountZ": 57,
  "quarter": "2004 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2004 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 41,
  "CountX": 30,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2005 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 40,
  "CountX": 27,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2005 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 17,
  "CountZ": 56,
  "quarter": "2005 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 41,
  "CountX": 26,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2005 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 49,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 59,
  "quarter": "2006 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 17,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2006 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2006 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 40,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2006 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 57,
  "quarter": "2007 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2007 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 21,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2007 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 25,
  "CountZ": 70,
  "quarter": "2007 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2008 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 30,
  "CountZ": 69,
  "quarter": "2008 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 26,
  "CountZ": 53,
  "quarter": "2008 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 30,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2008 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 70,
  "quarter": "2009 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2009 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2009 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 27,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2009 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 42,
  "CountX": 28,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2010 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 43,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2010 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2010 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 45,
  "CountX": 24,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2010 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2011 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 65,
  "quarter": "2011 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 34,
  "CountX": 21,
  "CountZ": 64,
  "quarter": "2011 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 48,
  "CountX": 23,
  "CountZ": 69,
  "quarter": "2011 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 49,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 56,
  "quarter": "2012 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 19,
  "CountZ": 51,
  "quarter": "2012 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 62,
  "quarter": "2012 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 42,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2012 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 46,
  "CountX": 18,
  "CountZ": 59,
  "quarter": "2013 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 39,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 51,
  "quarter": "2013 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 32,
  "CountX": 29,
  "CountZ": 68,
  "quarter": "2013 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 35,
  "CountX": 28,
  "CountZ": 61,
  "quarter": "2013 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 31,
  "CountX": 19,
  "CountZ": 63,
  "quarter": "2014 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 16,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2014 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 37,
  "CountX": 15,
  "CountZ": 57,
  "quarter": "2014 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 44,
  "CountX": 26,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2014 Q4"
}, {
  "CountY": 33,
  "CountX": 23,
  "CountZ": 58,
  "quarter": "2015 Q1"
}, {
  "CountY": 46,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 52,
  "quarter": "2015 Q2"
}, {
  "CountY": 48,
  "CountX": 20,
  "CountZ": 61,
  "quarter": "2015 Q3"
}, {
  "CountY": 50,
  "CountX": 22,
  "CountZ": 60,
  "quarter": "2015 Q4"
}];

function filterByQuarter(quarter) {
  return function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.quarter.indexOf(quarter) !== -1;
  }
}

function filterData(chart, quarter) {
  chart.dataProvider = chartData.filter(filterByQuarter(quarter));
  chart.validateData();
}

function resetChart(chart) {
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.validateData();
}

charts['chartdiv'] = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "categoryField": "quarter",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountX"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountY"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountZ"
  }]
});

charts['chartdiv2'] = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "depth3D": 30,
  "angle": 30,
  "categoryField": "quarter",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "graphs": [{
    "type": "column",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountX"
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountY"
  }]
});

charts['chartdiv3'] = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv3", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "categoryField": "quarter",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "100%"
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "type": "column",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountX"
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountY"
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "valueField": "CountZ"
  }]
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.filterButton'),
  function(button) {
    if (button.dataset.quarter === "reset") {
      button.addEventListener('click', resetChart.bind(null, charts[button.dataset.chart]));
    } else {
      button.addEventListener('click', filterData.bind(null, charts[button.dataset.chart], button.dataset.quarter));
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q1" data-chart="chartdiv">Q1</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q2" data-chart="chartdiv">Q2</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q3" data-chart="chartdiv">Q3</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q4" data-chart="chartdiv">Q4</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="reset" data-chart="chartdiv">Reset</button>
</div>
<div class="chart" id="chartdiv"></div>
<hr>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q1" data-chart="chartdiv2">Q1</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q2" data-chart="chartdiv2">Q2</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q3" data-chart="chartdiv2">Q3</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q4" data-chart="chartdiv2">Q4</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="reset" data-chart="chartdiv2">Reset</button>
</div>
<div class="chart" id="chartdiv2"></div>
<hr>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q1" data-chart="chartdiv3">Q1</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q2" data-chart="chartdiv3">Q2</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q3" data-chart="chartdiv3">Q3</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="Q4" data-chart="chartdiv3">Q4</button>
  <button class="filterButton" data-quarter="reset" data-chart="chartdiv3">Reset</button>
</div>
<div class="chart" id="chartdiv3"></div>
```

Note that I moved the forEach initializer so that the charts object can be defined before the listeners are added. This works off the assumption in the comments that the charts all the share the same data array.

Comment: This looks great! :-O but I'm having some troubles implementing this … to start, maybe because I'm using amCharts to display multiple graphs, not only one … is this possible too? (like with `AmCharts.ready(function() { var chartY1 = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart(); chartY1.dataProvider = myNumbers; …`)

Comment: This should work fine regardless if you're doing it the old object oriented way (i.e. `new AmCharts.AmSerialChart()`) or the current JSON method of creating charts. The same properties exist in both scenarios. Note that AmCharts.ready is functionally equivalent to window.onload/$(document).ready()/etc, so you probably don't need it if you're already wrapping it in the native onload wrapper or including your script at the end of the page.

If you could provide a fiddle that represents your scenario and the issues you're running into, I could help point out what's wrong.

Comment: Also note that the example I provided assumes it has access to the chart instance. You'll need to adjust the code accordingly or include it in the ready wrapper so that everything is in the same scope.

Comment: I'm so glad you can help me! But it's actually pretty difficult to extract some data from my quite large js-file. In the end, I have multiple `#chartdivXX` and multiple `var chartQXX = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart…` … so there are about 7 chartQ-graphs, all building from one `var chartData`-dataArray

Comment: note: I'm getting your code to work – if there is only one graph. but since there are 7 graphs this code has to be added to, I kind of don't want to repeat the code 7 times. a DRY-solution would be great.

Comment: I'm assuming each chart has their own set of buttons, right? You could put your charts into some sort of array/object hashed by an ID that you can include in the buttons' data attribute. I can whip up a demo of that shortly.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133104/discussion-between-albuvee-and-xorspark).